# What call to the function will result in the following output?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, output

```
def doh(a, b, c):
    if a[str(b)] + c == a[c + 'x']:
        print(b + 2)
```

expect output:

```
11
```

Where do I start to approach? And what are these variables type?

Comment: You know `b + 2` has to be 11, so that one is 9.

Comment: Yeah, then how do I treat a and c to satisfy the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solution

Pass these values for variable a,b,c

variable a must be a dictionary, variable b should be integer 9 and variable c should be a string or alphabet

```
#function defenition
def doh(a, b, c):
    if a[str(b)] + c == a[c + 'x']:
        print(b + 2)

a = {'9':'d','cx':'dc'}
b=9
c='c'
doh(a, b, c)
```

> Result

11

> Another Solution

```
a = {'9':'michael','hix':'michaelhi'}
b=9
c='hi'
doh(a, b, c)
```

So the relation should be like in the following figure.
[image: go to this link to see the relation]

I hope this would be helpful